# Relative Velocity-Shortest Distance

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

In this diagram, how close can ship A get to ship B?
Ship A can travel in any direction-Ship B's direction is fixed.

I tried to do this
$f\left( c \right)=\left( closest\; distance \right)$ and find the minimum but it got very messy. Does anyone know a nicer way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Does ship $A$ follow $B$?

Comment: A picks the optimum angle that will get him as close as possible to B, so initially he's not travelling directly towards B

Comment: Ah okay I get it now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$A$'s speed $$||\frac{d}{dt}A(t)||=12$$

or the position $$A(t)=\langle a_x t, a_u t\rangle$$

and $$12=\sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2}$$

$$B(t)=\langle 200, 20t \rangle$$

Then the question is to find the optimum $a_x,a_y,t$ such that $|A(t)-B(t)|$ is minimized.

Minimize $$D(a_x,a_y,t)=|| \langle a_x t-200, a_y t-20t \rangle ||$$

$$=\sqrt{(a_xt-200)^2+(a_yt-20)^2}$$

Subject to constraint equation

$$144=a_x^2+a_y^2$$

We can see $D$ is min possibly when $$\nabla D= \langle \frac{\partial}{\partial u} \sqrt{(u-200)^2+(v-20)^2}, \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \sqrt{(u-200)^2+(v-20)^2} \rangle = \langle 0,0 \rangle $$

With $$u=a_xt$$

$$v=a_yt$$

Then $\frac{u}{a_x}=\frac{v}{a_y}$ giving the relation between $a_x$ and $a_y$. Then $144=a_x^2+a_y^2$ constrains it.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the velocity of B from A.

Then minimize according to the relative movement.